# remove all non-alphanum and multiple spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let a = "`!@A#$%A^&*A    789^&*(+_)JH?></.,":';-";
```

I need to remove all non-alphanum characters except dash and replace multiple spaces with a single space.

So the result should be - `AAA 789JH-`

Here is my try - without success:

```
a = a.replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 -]","");
a = a.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: `a.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')`

Comment: Letters like `éèçàñ` will still be kept, though. Not sure if intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
a.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
```

The `/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/g` regex will match multiple occurrences (`g` modifier does that) of 1 or more (see `+` quantifier) chars other than letters, digits, spaces or/and hyphens.

If you need to match any whitespace, replace the space with `\s`.

Note that `\s\s+` is equal to `\s{2,}` where `{2,}` is a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) matching 2 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern.

See the JS demo:

```js
let a = "`!@A#$%A^&*A    789^&*(+_)JH?></.,\":';-";
console.log(a.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' '));
```